# Floor constraint with bumps?

Tags: animation, constraints

I am making an animation with a car and was wondering if there was a way to integrate bumps into the floor constraint, so that the wheels would automatically go over the bumps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that, by creating a floor marker and using a shrinkwrap constraint to raise it up the level of any bumps:

[image]

The wheel's armature has a wheel parent, an axle, and a floor bone.  Both the axle and the floor are parented to the wheel parent.

The floor bone is raised to the level of the mesh by a shrinkwrap constraint, as pictured.  (Not lowered, but you can build that in with a second constraint if you want.)  The axle has a floor constraint (with offset) targeting the floor bone.  As the wheel parent moves over a bump, the floor bone raises to the level of the bump, which raises the floored axle bone.

Comment: I mean, wow. That should do it. I honestly completely forgot about this post because it was made 3 whole years ago. I appreciate the help though.

Comment: @Soper Frazzy Ehhh, it was in the list of unsolved, and I couldn't find an answer to my own problem, so.... :)